# Mass change opportunity types

Tags: record-type

I'm a new Salesforce admin. We have imported lots of opportunities from old and dirty data.  I have a number of opportunities which have imported as type A and I want to change them to a different opportunity record type en-masse.  Is this possible to do from the setup console, or do I have to write code to do it?

Comment: You can update the records using [data loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=5). Are you having issues with that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way not involving coding would be actually to export the records that need to be updated, change the RecordTypeId (or any other field you need) in excel or libra office and then import (update) the records :).

Just side note: Libra Office handles CSV files much better than Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Because Opportunities cannot be updated using Data Import Wizard, and while 
there are other options too viz., using [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/about.php), but as an Admin I will start with [**Data Loader**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=5). The steps that typically will need to be performed here as you have already imported the records will be:

1. Export the records
2. Make the changes on the record type that you need
3. Update the records

There are good documentation around this topic as how you can do this. The below pointers will help you to get started on this:

- [Use Data Loader to Export Data](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/import-and-export-with-data-management-tools/use-data-loader-to-export-data)
- [Use Data Loader to Update Data](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/import-and-export-with-data-management-tools/use-data-loader-to-import-data)
- [Import Opportunities into Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323825&type=1)